# microk8s install problem "cni plugin not initialized"

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Upgraded to PC to ubuntu 20.04 and having problems re-installing microk8s (1.19 and 1.20 have the same issue on my PC).

starting fresh to demo problem

```
snap remove microk8s
```

Following instructions on [Install MicroK8s](https://microk8s.io/docs)

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.19
```

result:

```
microk8s (1.19/stable) v1.19.5 from Canonical✓ installed
```

Step: Join the group

```
sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER
sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube
su - $USER
```

Step: Check the status

```
microk8s status --wait-ready
```

Result: Hangs forever

Figure out what is going on:

```
microk8s inspect
```

The tar files contain lots of

```
Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized

dial tcp 127.0.0.1:16443: connect: connection refused
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue on a new Ubuntu 20.04.1 Server install and following the same instructions... e.g.

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.19
```

What worked for me was using the 1.18 channel

```
sudo snap remove microk8s
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.18/stable
```

And then refreshing to 1.19 once microk8s 1.18 became ready...

```
sudo snap refresh microk8s --classic --channel=1.19/stable
```

Don't ask me why this worked but it did.

Comment: I had similar issues with microk8s 1.20 on Debian 11. Reinstalling with 1.21 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/ hosts file there should be these lines

127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.1.1 name you servers

It's funny in microk8s 1.18 all works good)

Comment: I don't get it, can you be more precise please ?